# Python PLY DATA token value is None

Tags: python, ply

I'm trying to make a programing language in python using PLY. While at first it was easy playing around with the parser because the data types were simpler, I now want to expand it.

I have the following code:

```
def p_show(p):
  '''statement : SHOW LPAREN DATA RPAREN'''
  
  print(p.slice)

def p_data(p):
  '''DATA : INT
          | STRING'''
  p[0] = p[1]
```

I expected that in `p.slice` the value of DATA would be the LexToken because of p_data. I also played around with returns and more. How do I change p.slice from:

```
[statement, LexToken(SHOW,'show',1,0), LexToken(LPAREN,'(',1,4), DATA, LexToken(RPAREN,')',1,10)]
```

to actually showing the value in instead of just 'DATA' which has a None value

Comment: You need to show more code, ideally a [mre], since the problem could be anywhere between the lexer and the parser (and most likely the lexer).  Why is `DATA` in all caps, by the way? (Not a problem here, but it seems misleading.)

Comment: In the end, adding ```return p``` in the end worked. Now the .value of the DATA token is the value of I needed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.